# Convert Mapbox Vector Tiles to Longitude and Latitude

Tags: python, coordinate-system, mapbox, vector-tiles

I am using [Mapbox's QA Tiles](http://osmlab.github.io/osm-qa-tiles/) and Python to access OSM data. While the tile-based approach is very handy I got stuck with how the geometry is saved. Apparently, coordinates are optimized for Mapbox's rendering needs and are '[vector tile grid coordinates](https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/specification/)'. To my surprise, I can't find any reference that would help me to understand what they actually did.

In my case, I want to check if a location (as latitude and longitude) are within an OSM area (Polygon or Multipolygon). This is what I got from the QA tile:

`{
  "osm": {
    "version": 2, 
    "features": [
      {
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point", 
          "coordinates": [
            95810, 
            1041260
          ]
        }, 
        "type": 1, 
        "properties": {
          "@uid": 144382, 
          "backrest": "yes", 
          "@id": 3072121792, 
          "@timestamp": 1410453825, 
          "@changeset": 25372130, 
          "amenity": "bench", 
          "@user": "SHuehne", 
          "@version": 1, 
          "@type": "node"
        }, 
        "id": 0
      },
      …
    ]
   "extent": 1048576
  }
}`

This is the example node [in OSM](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/3072121792), the QA tile is z=12, x=2163, y=1435.

Answer (score 6):

I kept on reading and I guess I found the answer myself. I won't delete the answer, maybe someone else will bump into the same problem.

[mapbox-vector-tile](https://github.com/tilezen/mapbox-vector-tile) is the library I use and its documentation explains how they transformation are done: https://github.com/tilezen/mapbox-vector-tile#coordinate-transformations-for-encoding

Comment: to convert the co-ords to latitude-longitude: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/460173/44746

Comment: i've shared a full working code solution here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/475399/44746 , there was a missing final step of pixel2deg

Answer (score 3):

@linqu's answer the best for Python as per your question.

A JS implementation which extracts the VT geometry as GeoJSON is at https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-js/blob/master/lib/vectortilefeature.js#L129

Other JS tools which can help:

- https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-js
- https://github.com/mapbox/vt2geojson