# Decoding Mapbox Vector Tiles?

Tags: gdal, geopandas, ogr2ogr, mapbox, vector-tiles

I'm using the [Mapbox Vector Tile API](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/vector-tiles-api/) and I want to get the data into one or multiple [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/) GeoDataFrame. (Python)

After I download the .mvt file, how do I decode it?

What I've tried already:

- [mapbox-vector-tile](https://github.com/tilezen/mapbox-vector-tile) library, this decodes the file into a dictionary (JSON) but does not transform the given coordinates.
- [python-vt2geojson](https://github.com/Amyantis/python-vt2geojson) library, this transforms the coordinates but the information about the layers is lost.
- `ogr2ogr` with `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON $file_path_json $file_path_mvt -oo x=$x -oo y=$y -oo z=$z` but this yields the error

```
ERROR 1: Layer 'aeroway' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer aeroway (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
```

- `ogr2ogr` with `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" $file_path_shp $file_path_mvt -oo x=$x -oo y=$y -oo z=$z` but this yields the error

```
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'admin_level' to 'admin_leve'
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'name_script' to 'name_scrip'
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'text_anchor' to 'text_ancho'
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'name_zh-Hans' to 'name_zh-Ha'
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'name_script' to 'name_scrip'
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'name_zh-Hant' to 'name_zh-_1'
Warning 1: One or several characters couldn't be converted correctly from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1.  This warning will not be emitted anymore.
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'name_script' to 'name_scrip'
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'shield_text_color' to 'shield_tex'
ERROR 1: Attempt to write non-linestring (GEOMETRYCOLLECTION) geometry to ARC type shapefile.
ERROR 1: Unable to write feature 91 from layer road.
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer road (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
```

Has anyone a clue of how to decode Mapbox Vector Tile files into files that can be read into GeoPandas with the coordinates transformed to longitude and latitude?

Comment: MVT is a display format - it would be much easier to fetch the data in a better format for importing

Comment: I looked for different solutions, but Mapbox Vector Tiles API seems to be the best solution. My goal is explained in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67916246/how-to-check-if-a-water-body-is-near-a-given-coordinate-very-often/)

Comment: so just download the OSM data as suggested in that answer

Comment: What do you mean by "does not transform the given coordinates."?

Comment: @Stefan it returns the coordinates in pixel coordinates between 0 and 4096 rather than Mercator or Geodetic coordinates.

Comment: Using [mercantile](https://github.com/mapbox/mercantile) you can transform pixel coordinates into geographic coordinates

Answer (score 1):

Using the [mapbox-vector-tile](https://github.com/tilezen/mapbox-vector-tile) library you can convert back to WGS84 decimal degrees if you know the zoom, column (tile_x), and row (tile_y) of the tile. E.g.:

```py
import mapbox_vector_tile
import math

def pixel2deg(xtile, ytile, zoom, xpixel, ypixel, extent = 4096):
  n = 2.0 ** zoom
  xtile = xtile + (xpixel / extent)
  ytile = ytile + ((extent - ypixel) / extent)
  lon_deg = (xtile / n) * 360.0 - 180.0
  lat_rad = math.atan(math.sinh(math.pi * (1 - 2 * ytile / n)))
  lat_deg = math.degrees(lat_rad)
  return (lon_deg, lat_deg)

mapbox_vector_tile.decode(your_mvt, 
  transformer = lambda x, y: pixel2deg(tile_x, tile_y, tile_zoom, x, y)
)
```

Comment: What exactly is your_mvt? A Path to an MVT file, or a binary object?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/801#issuecomment-408111458, GDAL only supports one layer per file. Thus, you need to append layer name after your GDAL command.

For example,
`ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON $file_path_json $file_path_mvt -oo x=$x -oo y=$y -oo z=$z aeroway` will generate a geojson file for the aeroway layer.