# Extracting specific layers from the PBF file

Tags: ordnance-survey

Trying to get only a specific feature (coniferous forest) from the vectors, I first tried to use the Zoomstack layers, but they merge all the woodland types into one. With the vectors however, they definitely have three styles for the three forest types, so the data must be available. (You can see this in the github style sheets.)

All the examples use something like leaflet to render the map. But I don't want to render the map, I want to extract only the woodland types from the protobuf file.

I can get the file like so:

```
https://api.os.uk/maps/vector/v1/vts/tile/12/1247/2018\?key\=MYKEY\&srs\=3857
```

but I can't see how to get the protobuf specs, or how things like Leaflet knows how to unpack it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordnance survey .pbf (Google Protobuf files) currently use the Mapbox Vector Tile specification version 2.1. This allows them to open in software like QGIS and Mapbox. After also encountering the same problem, Ordnance Survey's documentation currently doesn't appear to mention this.

Use the [protobuf compiler](https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/) in your language of choice with the [Mapbox Vector Tile 2.1 .proto specification](https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec/blob/master/2.1/vector_tile.proto) in order to unpack the .pbf file. You'll get a Tile object with the set of layers in there.

For completeness, the .proto is also copied below:

```protobuf
package vector_tile;

option optimize_for = LITE_RUNTIME;

message Tile {

        // GeomType is described in section 4.3.4 of the specification
        enum GeomType {
             UNKNOWN = 0;
             POINT = 1;
             LINESTRING = 2;
             POLYGON = 3;
        }

        // Variant type encoding
        // The use of values is described in section 4.1 of the specification
        message Value {
                // Exactly one of these values must be present in a valid message
                optional string string_value = 1;
                optional float float_value = 2;
                optional double double_value = 3;
                optional int64 int_value = 4;
                optional uint64 uint_value = 5;
                optional sint64 sint_value = 6;
                optional bool bool_value = 7;

                extensions 8 to max;
        }

        // Features are described in section 4.2 of the specification
        message Feature {
                optional uint64 id = 1 [ default = 0 ];

                // Tags of this feature are encoded as repeated pairs of
                // integers.
                // A detailed description of tags is located in sections
                // 4.2 and 4.4 of the specification
                repeated uint32 tags = 2 [ packed = true ];

                // The type of geometry stored in this feature.
                optional GeomType type = 3 [ default = UNKNOWN ];

                // Contains a stream of commands and parameters (vertices).
                // A detailed description on geometry encoding is located in 
                // section 4.3 of the specification.
                repeated uint32 geometry = 4 [ packed = true ];
        }

        // Layers are described in section 4.1 of the specification
        message Layer {
                // Any compliant implementation must first read the version
                // number encoded in this message and choose the correct
                // implementation for this version number before proceeding to
                // decode other parts of this message.
                required uint32 version = 15 [ default = 1 ];

                required string name = 1;

                // The actual features in this tile.
                repeated Feature features = 2;

                // Dictionary encoding for keys
                repeated string keys = 3;

                // Dictionary encoding for values
                repeated Value values = 4;

                // Although this is an "optional" field it is required by the specification.
                // See https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec/issues/47
                optional uint32 extent = 5 [ default = 4096 ];

                extensions 16 to max;
        }

        repeated Layer layers = 3;

        extensions 16 to 8191;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All thanks to the selected answer!

In case someone else finds this and wants to do it in python, you can also just use the mapbox_vector_tile package to open it, then you don't need to install proto files. Something like this should do the trick:

```py
import mapbox_vector_tile
import requests
import geopandas as gpd

pbf = requests.get(url).content  # url is a vector tile from os with your key etc.
tile = mapbox_vector_tile.decode(pbf)
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(tile['Woodland:3']['features'])
```

Because unpacking the proto file yourself and formatting it nicely is quite a pain. Recommend this method.

Comment: to convert the co-ords to latitude-longitude: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/460173/44746