# Extract features in lat-long co-ordinates from vector tile layer PBF file, Python

Tags: python, vector-tiles, pbf

I'm trying to extract features using python from a vector tile layer's single .pbf tile :

```
https://indianopenmaps.fly.dev/google-buildings/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf
```

This tile layer comes from : https://github.com/ramSeraph/google_buildings_india, and when we add it on QGIS, it loads up properly, screenshot:

[image: QGIS vector tile layer preview]

From this vector layer's properties, seeing these CRS details:

```
Name    EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator
Units   meters
Method  Mercator
Celestial body  Earth
Accuracy    Based on World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble (EPSG:6326), which has a limited accuracy of at best 2 meters.
Reference   Dynamic (relies on a datum which is not plate-fixed)
```

So I'm assuming the source SRID is 3857.

One vector tile file: https://indianopenmaps.fly.dev/google-buildings/12/2934/1684.pbf

I'm using "mapbox-vector-tile" library (homepage: https://github.com/tilezen/mapbox-vector-tile) to decode the binary pbf data into geojson. Functional python code:

```py
import requests, mapbox_vector_tile
from pyproj import Transformer

url = "https://indianopenmaps.fly.dev/google-buildings/12/2934/1684.pbf"
response = requests.get(url)
pbf_data = response.content
# when printed, this shows: b'\x1a\xe2\x8f\x0cx\x02\n\x10google_building....

vector1 = mapbox_vector_tile.decode(tile=pbf_data)
print(vector1['google_buildings']['features'][0])
```

Output:

```json
{'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
   'coordinates': [[[5, 3922], [7, 3918], [1, 3916], [-1, 3919], [5, 3922]]]},
  'properties': {'confidence': 0.7949},
  'id': 0,
  'type': 'Feature'}
```

This is obviously not in lat-longs. So the Readme at "mapbox-vector-tile" github provides a way to convert to lat-longs, so I applied that:

```py
SRID_LNGLAT = 4326
SRID_SPHERICAL_MERCATOR = 3857
reverse_transformer = Transformer.from_crs(crs_from=SRID_SPHERICAL_MERCATOR, crs_to=SRID_LNGLAT, always_xy=True)

vector2 = mapbox_vector_tile.decode(tile=pbf_data, default_options={"transformer": reverse_transformer.transform})
print(vector2['google_buildings']['features'][0])
```

Output:

```json
{'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[4.491576420597607e-05, 0.035231923222862935], [6.28820698883665e-05, 0.03519599061828461], [8.983152841195214e-06, 0.03517802431599025], [-8.983152841195214e-06, 0.035204973769430485], [4.491576420597607e-05, 0.035231923222862935]]]}, 'properties': {'confidence': 0.7949}, 'id': 0, 'type': 'Feature'}
```

Unfortunately, even now I'm not getting this in lat-longs.
Those original co-ords ([5, 3922], [7, 3918]..) were looking suspect anyways - didn't seem like 3857 co-ords. I'm guessing they're relative to some place.

So, how do I get these co-ords in latitude-longitude? I know that this tile layer's data is proper, since QGIS is not having any problem in rendering it out-of-the-box.

### Related questions:

1. [Convert Mapbox Vector Tiles to Longitude and Latitude](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241906/convert-mapbox-vector-tiles-to-longitude-and-latitude) : Here the top-voted answer merely refers to the "mapbox-vector-tile" library's homepage, there's no code sample that shows how to convert to lat-longs, and following the transform process given in that homepage has given the above result. So, we're not having a complete answer there.
2. [Extracting specific layers from the PBF file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/451498/extracting-specific-layers-from-the-pbf-file) : answers here refer to the same protobuf to json conversion which is already successfully happening, but don't mention anything about transforming the output co-ords to lat-longs. So, we're not having a complete answer there.

Comment: Read the MVT specification https://mapbox.github.io/vector-tile-spec/. The coordinates in the vector tiles are always in the local tile units. The top-left corner of every tile is (0,0). For connecting MVT coordinates with real world coordinates you must know the tiling schema, and by the schema resolve where the tile 12/2936/1684 is located.

Answer (score 3):

Update: Came across this answer : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/460173/44746 posted at similar question that I hadn't found yet: [Decoding Mapbox Vector Tiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401541/decoding-mapbox-vector-tiles)

Updating my code to have a full working solution from tile url to shapefile:

```py
import requests, mapbox_vector_tile, math, json

def pixel2deg(xtile, ytile, zoom, xpixel, ypixel, extent = 4096):
    # from https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/460173/44746
    n = 2.0 ** zoom
    xtile = xtile + (xpixel / extent)
    ytile = ytile + ((extent - ypixel) / extent)
    lon_deg = (xtile / n) * 360.0 - 180.0
    lat_rad = math.atan(math.sinh(math.pi * (1 - 2 * ytile / n)))
    lat_deg = math.degrees(lat_rad)
    return (lon_deg, lat_deg)

url = "https://indianopenmaps.fly.dev/google-buildings/12/2934/1684.pbf"
tile_x = 2934
tile_y = 1684
tile_zoom = 12

response = requests.get(url)
pbf_data = response.content
# when printed, this shows: b'\x1a\xe2\x8f\x0cx\x02\n\x10google_building....

vector3 = mapbox_vector_tile.decode(tile=pbf_data, 
  transformer = lambda x, y: pixel2deg(tile_x, tile_y, tile_zoom, x, y)
)
print(vector3['google_buildings']['features'][0])

with open('shape1.geojson','w') as f:
    json.dump(vector3['google_buildings'],f)
```

Output:

```
{'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
  'coordinates': [[[77.8712010383606, 30.445454921154706],
    [77.87124395370483, 30.445380925465102],
    [77.87111520767212, 30.445343927599236],
    [77.87107229232788, 30.445399424392768],
    [77.8712010383606, 30.445454921154706]]]},
 'properties': {'confidence': 0.7949},
 'id': 0,
 'type': 'Feature'}
```

Now this looks like proper lat-longs!

And  the .geojson file when dropped over https://geojson.io/ :
[image]

The shoe fits!

Props to [Mark Egge](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/71120/mark-egge) for sharing the `pixel2deg` function, it was the missing link.